# Java class not running on OS X

Tags: java, macos

I have a simple program written in Java:

```
package edu.oakland.lecture;

public class Alfa {

    int a;

    public int getAttribute() {
        System.out.println("returning value of a");
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Alfa alfa = new Alfa();
        int number = alfa.getAttribute();
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

It compiles with javac on both windows (xp) and os x (lion), but it only runs on windows.

This is the command I use to compile the program:

`javac -d bin source/edu/oakland/lecture/Alfa.java`

This is the command I use to execute it:

`java -classpath bin; edu.oakland.lecture.Alfa` (I also tried `-cp` instead of `-classpath` in Terminal)

As I mentioned, I get the expected output on windows side, but I get this message on the os x side:

`-bash: edu.oakland.lecture.Alfa: command not found`

I know it has to be something stupid simple; what am I overlooking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classpath separator on UNIX-like systems (such as OS X) is ':', not ';'. Your command should just be

```
java -classpath bin edu.oakland.lecture.Alfa
```

If you actually did have several different components to your classpath, it would look like:

```
java -classpath bin:foo edu.oakland.lecture.Alfa
```

Comment: I knew it was simple..thanks so much! It looks like the colon is completely optional as well.

Comment: So in your edit 'Foo' would be a secondary class path folder correct?

Comment: This is very carefully covered in the Sun Java TUtorial

Comment: Yes, @Anders, you only use a separator if there is more than one path component, and yes, "foo" is an imaginary second component.